# Can docblocks reside outside the php file they are documenting?

Tags: php

I am building a composable form builder with a (simplified) class layout like this:

```
Field.php <- parent class
Boolean.php
Choice.php
Fieldset.php
Form.php
Text.php
```

I like to compose a form in a fluent manner similar to this:

```
$form = new Form('data');
$form->children([
    Field::Text('username')->label('username'),
    Field::Text('password')->label('password'),
    Field::Boolean('remember')->label('remember me')
]);
```

In order to achieve the `Field::Fieldtype()->...` syntactic sugar instantiation, instead of doing `(new FieldType())->...`, I have a `__callStatic()` method like so:

```
abstract class Field
{
    /**
     * @param $name
     * @param $arguments
     * @return Field
     * @throws FormsException
     */
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
    {
        $className = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . ucfirst($name);
        if (!class_exists($className)) {
            throw new FormsException('Class ' . $name . ' is not a registered field type');
        }
        $reflect = new ReflectionClass($className);
        return $reflect->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
    }

    ...

}
```

This is working correctly, and to make the IDE work with it, I have the following docblock:

```
/**
 * @method static \Forms\Boolean Boolean(string $name='')
 * @method static \Forms\Choice Choice(string $name='')
 * @method static \Forms\Fieldset Fieldset(string $name='')
 * @method static \Forms\File File(string $name='')
 * @method static \Forms\Text Text(string $name='')
 * @method static \Forms\MultipleChoice MultipleChoice(string $name='')
 * @method static \Forms\JSON JSON(string $name='')
 * @method static \Forms\TextArray TextArray(string $name='')
 * @method static \Forms\Submit Submit(string $name='')
 */
```

This is also working as expected, and the coding experience is pretty satisfactory when using a decent IDE.

What I would further like to do, is to (at some point during development) have automated generation of this docblock, that would scan a given directory for classes, and generate these docblock hints, so that if I expand the Field types on another part of the application, the new field types would also inform the IDE of their existence and the return types for each of the added classes.

The problem is that I do not want to have code that writes inside my class files, for obvious reasons, so the only logical alternative would be to have the docblock outside the file and somehow included in a way that the IDE makes sense of it.

**So my question is**: Is there a way to decouple docblocks and their referring classes in PHP, in such a way that the IDEs are still able to put two and two together and understand that this docblock refers to that class?